# how to pass input data to CloudFunctionInvokeFunctionOperator function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, airflow, airflow-scheduler

we are using cloud composer to trigger cloud function using `CloudFunctionInvokeFunctionOperator` operator. if we `input_data={}` then its triggering the function and function is failing with missing input, when we pass `input_data={"mail":"my_mail@acds.com"}`  then its showing below error

```
ERROR - <HttpError 400 when requesting https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my_pro/locations/europe/functions/my_fun:call?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "mail": Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "mail": Cannot find field.'}]}]">
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: You will need to show the code of `my_fun` function

Comment: i cant share the code due to security reason but i can trigger same function with gcloud functions call my_fun --data '{"mail":"my_mail@acds.com"}' command from cloud shell. will that help?

Comment: Hi yug.. do u have any answer for this query yet? Are u able to solve this using input_data parameter ..?

Answer (score 0):

You must provide your input data inside a dictionary encapsulated with `json.dumps()` with a key called `data`, as follows: `{"data": json.dumps({"mail":"my_mail@acds.com"})}`.

I did several tests and this is what worked for me.

I hope it helps!